# Javascript push() replacing element instead of appending

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

Here's a function I have written to add words to `local storage` using Javascript. In case you're wondering, this is my attempt at building a **search history** functionality for a simple dictionary lookup site.

```
function add2local(entry){
    var l = localStorage.length;

if(l==0){
    var lu = [entry];
    localStorage.setItem("w", JSON.stringify(lu));
}
else {
    var lu = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("w")); alert(lu);
    lu.push(entry); alert(lu);
}}
```

My understanding is the this function would keep appending its argument to local storage every time it's called. So, the first time I call it, I send it the word **pirate**. This gets added to the array and subsequently to the local storage as expected. The first `alert()` (the alert() functions are solely being used for testing) confirms this. The second time, I call it with the word **vampire**. Now, going by the function's logic, **vampire** should be *appended* to the array and thus the second `alert()` should output "pirate, vampire." And so it does.

But the third time around, say, I call the function with the word **foo**. This time around, it should output "pirate, vampire, foo" but instead shows "pirate, foo". Every subsequent call simply replaces the second word with the new word instead of appending it. What might I be doing wrong here? Am I misunderstanding how `push()` works?

Comment: You never put  the modified array back into local storage after the push.

Comment: Not sure I understand the "irrelevant" part. Won't I need to initiate the array if there's nothing in local storage already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` condition and logic is incorrect; it is irrelevant how many items `localStorage` has, but it is very important to re-save the modified array.

In any case, I suspect an impl. might look as so:

```
function add2local(entry){
    // load entries - if there are none, we simulate an empty array to load
    var lu = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("w") || "[]");
    // add new entry
    lu.push(entry);
    // write back - so change is not lost between function calls
    localStorage.setItem("w", JSON.stringify(lu));
    // return all local entries saved - for use from the caller
    return lu;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that `JSON.parse()` will throw a `SyntaxError` if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Why check the storage length? You don't care. Fetch the key and if it's null then default to empty array.

```
function add2local (entry) {
  var key = "w"
  var value = localStorage.getItem(key)
  if (value) {
    value = JSON.parse(value)
  } else {
    value = []
  }
  value.push(entry)
  localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value))
}
```